# Python2.7 is performing much worse then Python2.5 for my Appengine app

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine

I'm seeing a huge difference in performance between py2.7 threaded and py2.5.. py2.5 is performing 2-4 times better (depending on specific server url call) creating lower latency and less cpu usage (ie costs me a lot less to run the same server under py2.5)  Here are some stats.. seems very odd as py2.7 is advertised to be more efficient and cheaper.   Anyone else seeing this?  Here are a couple of screen shots showing performance.. I'm comparing the RuntimeMCyles and the Avg Latency for the various server url calls to determine performance.  The only difference between these two are py25 vs py27, I haven't changed any of the code otherwise:

Py2.7 with threading:

[image: Py2.7 with threading]

Py2.5 (the py2.5 server has been run on much fewer requests here.. but it's tracking the same over time so this is a good representation):

[image: Py2.5]

Comment: have you set `threadsafe: true` in `app.yaml`? (Assuming that your application is indeed threadsafe.)

Comment: It's hard to draw direct comparisons between threaded 2.7 and 2.5 runtime.  What I have observed is if you have longish requests > 100ms 2.7 with threading seems to be slower overall.  I suppose thats an artifact of single process and an app not using async calls etc...  You haven't mentioned if your using db or ndb.  You should probably run 2.7 without threading to see if 2.5 and 2.7 is comparable.  It seems that 2.7 threading keeps instance numbers down but does not necessarily makes things faster due to contention for resource.

Comment: Threading in 2.7 will reduce the need for new instance starts. Those can be slow, and can drive down performance.

Comment: I do have threadsafe: true.  I am using NDB.  I'm less concerned about speed at the moment, more concerned about price.  With 2.7 threadsafe: True my current traffic costs about $4, with py 2.5 the same server is costing about $2.30 for comparable traffic.  I can try 2.7 with threadsafe: False and see what happens.  BTW, I also have the scheduler throttled way back in both cases trying to limit the number of instances fired up.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue sounds like it could be caused by code that isn't thread safe.

I would try attaching [cProfile](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/commontasks#profiling) or the [Google App Engine Mini Profiler](https://github.com/kamens/gae_mini_profiler) and seeing if that sheds any light on the issue.

Something else to check is [this](http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe) simple guide on prepping your app for migration to Python 2.7.